# Rotate text (not an image) in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, rotation

How can you get text (not an image) to rotate on its axis in Android?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class that extends `TextView`, and then override the `onDraw` method, like this:

```
public class MyRotatedTextView extends TextView {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();

        float py = this.getHeight() / 2.0f;
        float px = this.getWidth() / 2.0f;
        canvas.rotate(180, px, py);

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

In this case the rotational axis goes trough the `TextView`'s center.

Comment: Hi rfsbraz,
Thank's for your answer.

I'm very new on programming in Java/Android, so I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge ;-)
I created a new class called MyRotatedTextView.
I use the class like this in my main activity:

String txtsong ="This is a songtitle";
MyRotatedTextView txt1 = (MyRotatedTextView)findViewById(R.id.songtitle);
txt1.setText(txtsong);               
My screen goes blank when I try.
There must certainly be something that I have misunderstood :-)

Again thank you in advance for your help!

Per.

Comment: Now I got it to work.  
But the only thing that happens is that the text is upside down!  
I would really like to have my text to rotate as in my example.  
Perhaps it should be built-animation or the like.  
I go to Google for answers.